# Windows Bacup Image - on live system?

Tags: windows, backup

I remember the old days, when many people used Norton Ghost. It was started from a bootable floppy disk and then one was able to create or restore system images.

Today I use the built-in Windows Backup Image system. What interests me most is that the image is being created while the system is fully operational and the application doesn't even ask user not to use other applications. Since the backup mechanism has to move ~100Gb from one volume to another, it is obvious, that system files (logs, configuration files etc.) will be changed during this operation, what - in worst case scenario - may possibly lead to unstable system (one file backed up before some important operation, second one - after).

I guess guys at Microsoft are smarter than I, so mostly likely this situation won't occur. But then how the backup tool overcomes the mentioned problem?

(By the way, recent versions of Norton Ghost does the same - backup is performed on live system)

Comment: It took me 2 reads to understand the question. I think your saying since it takes time to create an image there can be no guaranteed that files (system files, config files etc) will be in the same state (will not have changed) between the start of taking the image and the end of taking an image. You are asking either how they do it, or if it's safe. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @Dave Indeed, I'm more interested in how it is being done. If you create image when system is not live, you receive freezed-in-time image. But when system is alive, files change constantly.

Comment: Microsoft use Volume Shadow Copy https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee923636%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Good explanation at David Marshall's link.  Short version: it takes a snapshot of the system and backs up the snapshot.  The backup isn't of the live system (it doesn't reflect ongoing changes).